# Let and Get array of fixed size

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a class that has a fixed-size array of `Double`, for example

```
Private m_values(8) as Double
```

What is the correct syntax for the `Let` and `Get` methods for an array?

```
Public Property Let Values (RHS(8) as Double)
    m_values = RHS
End Property

Public Property Get Values() as Double
    Values = m_values
End Property
```

The specific parts of the syntax I am unclear about:

a. In the `Let` method, is `RHS(8) as Double` the correct way to pass an array of 8 `Double`?
b. Can I copy one array to another simply using assignment? (e.g. `m_values = values`)
c. For the `Get` method, is it correct for the function to be declared `as Double` or should it be something like `as Double(8)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to declare a property that can hold arrays is as `Variant` property.

```
Private m_values As Variant

Public Property Let Values(RHS As Variant)
    m_values = RHS
End Property

Public Property Get Values() As Variant
    Values = m_values
End Property

Public Sub Test()
    Dim x(8) As Double
    x(1) = 123.55
    x(2) = 456.45
    x(5) = 789.66
    x(8) = 123.777

    ' assign value to property
    Values = x

    ' get value from property
    Dim y() As Double
    y = Values

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(y)
        Debug.Print y(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to keep the following rules:

```
'starting point- array with 8 elements
Dim arrStart(8) As Double
    arrStart(8) = 1     'here- for testing with Local window

'passing array to another...Variant type variable
    'no array declaration required
Dim arrVariant As Variant
    arrVariant = arrStart

'passing array to another Double variable
    'dynamic array declaration required
Dim arrEmpty() As Double
    arrEmpty = arrStart
```

These rules work also when passing variable (as an parameter) to another property, function or subroutine. This also means that you can't declare Get Property as an array and you should declare it as a Variant type.